# Adding environment variable to Cloudformation ECS + Fargate deployment

Tags: docker-compose, google-cloud-functions, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

Our images have environment variables that ought to be defined during docker run, any idea how to add this variables into the cloudformation file. We currently have something like:

```
Task:
Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
Properties:
  Family: testenv
  Cpu: 256
  Memory: 512
  NetworkMode: 
  RequiresCompatibilities:
    - FARGATE
  ExecutionRoleArn: !ImportValue ECSTaskExecutionRole
  ContainerDefinitions:
    - Name: bonalds
      Image: gcr.io/zonalds-21/id-me:latest // image comes from gcr
      Cpu: 256
      Memory: 512
      PortMappings:
        - ContainerPort: 4567
          Protocol: tcp
      LogConfiguration:
        LogDriver: 
        Options:
          awslogs-group: 'zonalds'
          awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
          awslogs-stream-prefix: 'routme'
```

I can't seem to find any info in the AWS documentation, what would be the best way to add the environment variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your container definition can hold environment variables.

```
ContainerDefinitions:
    - Name: bonalds
      Image: gcr.io/zonalds-21/id-me:latest // image comes from gcr
      Cpu: 256
      Environment:
        - Name: Test
          Value: 'test'
      Memory: 512
      PortMappings:
        - ContainerPort: 4567
          Protocol: tcp
      LogConfiguration:
        LogDriver: 
        Options:
          awslogs-group: 'zonalds'
          awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
          awslogs-stream-prefix: 'routme'
```

More information in the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html)

Comment: Note that you should be able to see these environment variables in container details after creation.